# How to secure connection strings in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, web-config

I see several others have posted this question, however, none of the solutions I've tried have fixed this yet.  I have a 32-bit XP running VS 2008 and I am trying to encrypt my connection string in my web.config file.

But I am getting the error: 
The configuration section '...' was not found.  Failed!

The command I give it:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>Aspnet_regiis.exe -pe "system.we
b/AdventureWorksConnectionString2" -app "/Documents and Settings/Admin/My Docume
nts/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/AddFileToSQL2"

Also, how does -app map virtual directory?  In other words the path above is the directory right below c:.  Is this the correct path to use?  And AddFileToSQL2 is the name of my project, although it is part of the AddFileToSQL solution.

I have this folder web shared with all of the permissions.

And the relevant part of my web.config file:

```
  <add name="AdventureWorksConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=SIDEKICK;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Persist Security Info=true; User ID=AdventureWorks;Password=sqlMagic"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With DPAPI, you can only encrypt whole sections as far as I know. Thus, you cannot encrypt just your one connection string but the entire connectionStrings section. Second the `-app` refers to the virtual path to the application on your IIS server in which it should find the given section and config file. Thus, if your site look like this:

```
root
    /appFoo
```

And you wanted to encrypt the connection strings in /appFoo you would do

`aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/appFoo"`

[How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, however, now when I publish this to http://localhost/AddFileToSQL2/ it says Publish Succeeded but then I do not see it listed under C:\inetpub\ directory.  Should it be listed there after publishing?